# Cosa sono le "labardazze"?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Il sorriso dell'ignoto marinaio*, di Vincenzo Consolo, ho letto:

> Schiavati catenacci e serratura, tirate spranghe e **labardazze**, sciolte catene e schiusa l'inferriata, ci trovammo sulla bocca ovale dell'ingresso. Matafù precedeva con la lanterna.

Qualcuno di voi sa spiegare cos'è una "labardazza"? Non hi trovato questo termine in nessun dizionario. Si tratta di un sicilianismo?

Answer (score 1):

Ho trovato in [*SOTTO IL VELAME, 1993 – 2003 Dieci anni di studi danteschi e tradizionali - IV*](http://www.associazionears.eu/area_tematica_05/sotto_velame/sotto_velame_04.pdf) un riferimento preciso al passo da te citato:

> La galera sotterranea in cui si introduce il barone Mandralisca, come
> ogni luogo di detenzione che si rispetti, è ben chiusa, non presenta
> cioè possibilità di uscita da parte di chi vi sta dentro. Ciò lo si
> evince in maniera piuttosto chiara dal testo, quando il barone,
> descrivendo il momento di entrare, scrive nella sua memoria:
> “Schiavati catenacci e serratura, tirate spranghe e labardazze,
> sciolte catene e schiusa l’inferriata, ci trovammo sulla bocca ovale
> dell’ingresso”. (142) Si percepisce come questo ingresso sia ben
> custodito. L’uscita, a chiunque si trovi ad esservi detenuto, è
> impedita da un “cancello di ferro massiccio a grate strette” (142),
> ben serrato e assicurato da tutta una serie di chiavistelli, sbarre e
> serrature. Anche l’altra estremità della prigione non presenta
> aperture di sorta. Quando il barone discende nell’abisso di questo
> luogo di pena, come oramai sappiamo, scorge sulle pareti le scritte
> dei detenuti. A tale proposito, nel testo leggiamo: “Sulla prima, dopo
> la giravolta del vestibolo, ove ancora la solare luce la lambiva,
> LIBIRTAA scorsi sulla parete, e più sotto, alla terza, alla quinta, e
> sino in fondo, ove una pietra concava formava l’estremo apice e
> chiudeva questo vortice (fora vi sbatteva di contra la maretta,
> s’udiva la risacca), al barbaglio fumoso della lampa, altre parole
> vidi di scrittura fresca”. (144, corsivi nostri). Anche l’altra
> estremità del sotterraneo, quindi, non presenta scappatoie. Si noti
> come la struttura descritta, corredata di un “vestibolo”, formata come
> un “vortice” con tornanti numerati , si rifaccia, palesemente, al
> modello dantesco. Si faccia attenzione, comunque, al fatto che questo
> è un “vestibolo” caratterizzato, fin dall’inizio, dalla libertà,
> mentre quello dantesco è un ingresso attraverso il quale si entra, ma
> dal quale non si può uscire

Il significato penso che sia quello di sbarre che terminano con una specie di gancio a forma di alabarda per essere agganciate a un qualche sostegno fissato al muro.

Comment: So cos'è una "alabarda" perché in catalano e in castigliano esiste esattamente lo stesso vocabolo, ma non riesco a immaginare un gancio a forma di alabarda per fermare una porta.